# Converting any delegate to delegate with object[] parameter

Tags: c#, .net, object, delegates, func

I want to convert any delegate returning, for example bool, where first parameter is `MyClass` type and other arguments are convertible to `object`, for example

```
bool FirstMethod(MyClass foo, int integer, string text)
bool SecondMethod(MyClass foo, string text, AnotherClass bar)
```

to `Func<MyClass, object[], bool>`, so parameters after `MyClass` will be pushed in object array.
Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: There was some kind of error that delegate has invalid parameters - I don't have that code right now, I removed that couple of days ago, but I figured I have to have that

Comment: Could you at least specify the signature of method that you would like to implement? How would you pass _FirstMethod_ to this method? by instance of _Delegate_? How do you obtain this instance?

Answer (score 2):

You have in hand a:

```
delegate bool FirstMethod(MyClass foo, int integer, string text);
```

and you wish to write a conversion method that takes one of those and returns

```
Func<MyClass, object[], bool>
```

That's straightforward:

```
static Func<MyClass, object[], bool> Convert(FirstMethod f) =>
  (m, o) => f(m, (int)o[0], (string)o[1]);
```

Done. Just do that for every delegate type you've got to convert.

You could even make it an extension method if you like.

Comment: I have to store ANY delegate returning bool, with first parameter MyClass in the same variable type

Comment: @TheChilliPL: Right, so for each one, write the method above. It's one line of code.

Comment: For each one? There are infinite number of it. Object can be even custom made class argument, and argument count is not finite

Comment: @TheChilliPL: It sounds very much like you have an XY problem.  That is: you have some problem to solve, you have a wrong idea about how to solve it, and now you are having difficulty implementing that wrong idea.  What problem are you really trying to solve?